# Remove an element of a slice in a struct

Tags: go, methods, struct, slice

I have a struct "Guest" which contains metadata of a party guest (a unique ID, name, surname and a list of the unique IDs of the guests who are friends of this guest.

```
type Guest struct {
    id      int
    name    string
    surname string
    friends []int
}
```

I have the following code to remove an ID from the list of friends:

```
func (self Guest) removeFriend(id int) {
    for i, other := range self.friends {
        if other == id {
            self.friends = append(self.friends[:i], self.friends[i+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: The element I want to remove is overwritten by the shift of the elements, but the slice does not get shorter. Instead, the last element of the slice is multiplied.

To give an example: `guest1.friends` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. After I call `guest1.removeFriend(3)`, the result is `[1,2,4,5,5]` instead of the desired `[1,2,4,5]`.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any method that intends / does modify the receiver must use a pointer receiver.

Your `Guest.removeFriend()` method indeed tries to modify the receiver (of type `Guest`), namely its `friends` field (which is of slice type), but since you only used a value receiver, you are only modifying the `friends` field of a `Guest` copy. The original `Guest` value will have the unmodified slice value.

So you **must** use a pointer receiver:

```
func (self *Guest) removeFriend(id int) {
    // ...
}
```

Testing it:

```
g := &Guest{
    id:      1,
    name:    "Bob",
    surname: "Pats",
    friends: []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
}

fmt.Println(g)
g.removeFriend(3)
fmt.Println(g)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Bv-RVn6Btc)):

```
&{1 Bob Pats [1 2 3 4 5]}
&{1 Bob Pats [1 2 4 5]}
```

The explanation for what you see in your version that slices are small struct descriptors pointing to an array that actually holds the elements. In your example you modified the elements of the backing array, so the caller having the original slice will see those modifications, but the size of the original slice will not (cannot) change.

By using a pointer receiver, you will assign the new slice value (returned by `append()`) to the `friends` field of the original `Guest`, the slice value whose length will be smaller by 1 (due to the 1 removed element).

Also note that in Go using receiver names like `self` and `this` is not idiomatic, instead you could use `guest` or simply `g`.

Comment: Thanks. I used (self *Guest) previously but removed the pointer while trying to fix the problem. I added it again, but it did not fix the problem. I modified my question accordingly.

Comment: @AHahn94 It works for me. Added an example on the Go Playground. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It does indeed work. Maybe my problem is rather related to the fact that I have a slice of guest-objects like this:  var guests []Guest

Comment: @AHahn94 It works with slices too. Post a [mcve] if you want help with that.

Comment: I got it working. I had to change the slice from "var guests []Guest" to "var guests []*Guest", and then fix some argument and return types, as well as the initialization of the elements with "&Guest{}" instead of "Guest{}". After that, it works. Thank you realy much!