# How to write the scanner in a separate function to make it work?

Tags: go, user-input

In this code, I have created a function `TakeInput()` that will take the user input including the whitespaces also. But whenever I run this code and enter the name and school name, it does print the data for me.

Although if I write the `scanner` without any function, it takes the data with whitespaces.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func TakeInput(value string) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if scanner.Scan() {
        value = scanner.Text()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encountered:", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var name, school string
    fmt.Printf("Enter your name: ")
    TakeInput(name)

    fmt.Printf("Enter your school name: ")
    TakeInput(school)

    fmt.Println(name, school)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each parameter is a local copy inside the function. You must pass a pointer to `TakeInput()` (e.g. `&name` and `&school`) and modify the pointed value (e.g. `*value = scanner.Text()`, else you only modify the copy which is discarded upon function return.

For example:

```
func TakeInput(value *string) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if scanner.Scan() {
        *value = scanner.Text()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encountered:", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var name, school string
    fmt.Printf("Enter your name: ")
    TakeInput(&name)

    fmt.Printf("Enter your school name: ")
    TakeInput(&school)

    fmt.Println(name, school)
}
```

Also note that [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) has an internal buffer. It may read more than what is returned, which when you create a new `bufio.Scanner` in another `TakeInput()` call, it may not be able to read previously read, buffered and discarded data.

So create the scanner outside of `TakeInput()`, e.g.

```
func TakeInput(scanner *bufio.Scanner, value *string) {
    if scanner.Scan() {
        *value = scanner.Text()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encountered:", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    var name, school string
    fmt.Printf("Enter your name: ")
    TakeInput(scanner, &name)

    fmt.Printf("Enter your school name: ")
    TakeInput(scanner, &school)

    fmt.Println(name, school)
}
```

See related / similar questions:

[My object is not updated even if I use the pointer to a type to update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890706/my-object-is-not-updated-even-if-i-use-the-pointer-to-a-type-to-update-it/43890923#43890923)

[Remove an element of a slice in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435161/remove-an-element-of-a-slice-in-a-struct/47435232#47435232)